# How to import website graph data into google sheets

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, graph, google-sheets-formula

Essentially I'm working on a presentation and I would like to import this graph into google sheets it does not have to look the same I just need the data. I don't program in HTML so I'm not really sure what to do does anyone have ideas on how I could extract this graph data.

```
https://digitalik.net/btc/sf_model/#
```

I've tried using google sheets built-in HTML graph function but for some reason, it can't detect it so an alternative would be to download the data as an XML and paste it into sheets so that's also an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately not possible for a given site because it uses JavaScript and Google Sheets does not support web scraping of JS elements. you can test this simply by disabling JS for a given site and what's left can be scraped. in your case its nothing:

[image: 0]